# How to reduce number of selenium webdriver instances being spawned by scrapy on running crawl on a spider?

Tags: selenium, scrapy

On running crawl process for any spider, Scrapy tends to spawn a lot of (27 average varying between 19 - 30)  Firefox instances, even if the spider being run is not using selenium.

I have tried `driver.quit()` inside `def __del__(self)` in each of the spiders using selenium. The problem still persists.

The  Firefox instances stay open even after the crawling process is finished.

example spider using selenium:

```
import logging
import time
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import requests
import scrapy
import selenium
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

LOGGER.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

PATH_DIR = dirname(abspath(__file__))
GECKODRIVER_PATH = abspath(join(PATH_DIR, "../../geckodriver"))
WAIT_TIME = 10

class ExampleSpider(sso_singapore.SsoSpider):

    name = "Example"

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=GECKODRIVER_PATH)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def parse(self, response):

        meta = response.meta
        try:
            self.driver.get(response.url)
            body = self.driver.page_source
            try:
                element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, WAIT_TIME).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.ID, '//select[@id="rows_sort"]/option[text()="All"]')
                    )
                )
            except:
                pass
            response = HtmlResponse(
                self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding="utf-8"
            )

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
        finally:
            self.driver.quit()
       # Create Items based on response

    def start_requests(self):

        for url, meta in zip(urls, meta_list):
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=parse, meta=meta)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from scrapy import signals

class ExampleSpider(sso_singapore.SsoSpider):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="your_path")

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(ExampleSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.quit()
```

This should do the job.

More on Scrapy signals:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html

You can also use Pipeline if you have many spiders and don't want to add the same `driver.quit()` logic:

```
class YourPipeline:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        if hasattr(spider, 'driver'):
            spider.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, but the problem with this is the `def __init__(self)` doesn't work with scrapyd. does the *args and **kwargs fix that?

Comment: @beard_beer_code
It should work. I'm using `__init__` method in my spiders and I launch some of them with scrapyd. Do you receive any error? `*args` and `**kwargs` are there to make sure that if you (or scrapyd) pass arguments to Scrapy (for example, with `scrapy crawl myspider -a argument=value`), it doesn't fail.

Comment: This absolutely works, and just a small modification, if you remove `*args` from it, it works with scrapyd as well. Thanks a lot